# Shopping cart empty after view product page

Tags: magento, cookies, session-cookies, shopping-cart, magento-1.8

I have a problem with my shopping-cart, I can add a product to the shopping-cart but when I go to a product page the shopping-cart is empty.

I changed cookie settings multiple times, I have these setting:

> Cookie time : 86400 
>   Cookie path: / https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help 
>   Cookie domain: .domain.com 
>   Only http: Yes 
>   Restriction mode: No

Setting validation, all to no except validate HTTP_USER_AGENT to yes.

Comment: Do you have any full page cache there? varnish or something?

Comment: check if the session is properly established. Try to change session storage from files to db.

Comment: kuba_ceg has a good approach. if it works with db session storage you might have e.g. a permission problem!

Comment: Thank you for the answers! I dont use varnish, i try to change session storage to db (<session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>) but still the problems occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I have some new information about this problem, i know it works fine on a Windows 8.1 computer using Google Chrome. With IE on the same computer it doesnt work.